# Integrability of $\frac{1}{|x|^d}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

For $x \in \mathfrak R^d$,why is $\int_\limits{\{x; |x|\geq 1\}} \frac{1}{|x|^d} dx = \infty$ in Lebesgue integral?

It's hinted to apply Tonelli Theorem (Fubini Theorem) and use the fact that $\frac 1 x$ is not integrable over $[1,\infty)$, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Work in polar coordinates, and combine the facts that

- the integrand is a radial function
- the surface area of the sphere of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ scales like $r^{d - 1}$.

Comment: What's the Jacobian of polar coordinates in $d$ dimension?

Comment: @CYC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element

Answer (score 3):

Make the change of variables $x = 2y.$ Then $dx= 2^ddy,$ and the new domain of integration is $\{|y|>1/2\}.$ We get

$$\int_{|x|\ge 1} \frac{1}{|x|^d}\, dx = \int_{|y|\ge 1/2} \frac{1}{2^d|y|^d}\, 2^d\,dy = \int_{|y|\ge 1/2} \frac{1}{|y|^d}\, dy.$$

That's a contradiction unless these integrals $= \infty.$

Comment: That's a very nice approach.